# Mongodb, Mongoose , Multidocument aggregation of number and array field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My schemas goes like this

```
var group=new Schema({ 

    group_id:Number,
    group_name:String,
    country:String,
    member_count:Number,
    members:[member]

});

var member=new Schema({
    member_id:number,
    name:String,
    address:String,
    sex:String 
});
```

sample document

```
group
[{
  _id:55ff7fca8d3f6607114dc57d
  group_id:1001,
  group_name:"tango mike",
  country:"japan",
  member_count:3
  members:[
    {
      _id:44ff7fca8d3f6607114dc21c
      member_id:2001,
      member_name:"Bob martin" ,
      address:String,
      sex:String 
    },

    {
      _id:22ff7fca8d3f6607114dc22d
      member_id:2002,
      member_name:"Marry",  
      address:String,
      sex:String
    },

    {
      _id:44ff7fca8d3f6607114dc23e
      member_id:2003,
      member_name:"Alice" ,
      address:String,
      sex:String 
    }
  ]

},

{
  _id:55ff7fca8d3f6607114dc32h
  group_id:1002,
  group_name:"Love chat",
  country:"japan",
  member_count:2
  members:[
    {
      _id:44ff7fca8d3f6607114dc21c
      member_id:2011,
      member_name:"Henry martin" ,
      address:String,
      sex:String 
    },

    {
      _id:22ff7fca8d3f6607114dc22d
      member_id:2022,
      member_name:"George",  
      address:String,
      sex:String
    }


  ]

}

]
```

Above is the dummy situation I had created, Which is similar to the original situation on which I am working

I am trying to do this...
  1)Count total number of member from all group of country japan(by aggregating member_count field of all group)
        for above collection total_member_count should be 3+2
  2)List all members of all group of country japan
        for above collection total_member_list should be

```
 [{

           {
          _id:44ff7fca8d3f6607114dc21c
          member_id:2001,
          member_name:"Bob martin" ,
          address:String,
          sex:String 
        },

        {
          _id:22ff7fca8d3f6607114dc22d
          member_id:2002,
          member_name:"Marry",  
          address:String,
          sex:String
        },

        {
          _id:44ff7fca8d3f6607114dc23e
          member_id:2003,
          member_name:"Alice" ,
          address:String,
          sex:String 
        },

             {
          _id:44ff7fca8d3f6607114dc21c
          member_id:2011,
          member_name:"Henry martin" ,
          address:String,
          sex:String 
        },

        {
          _id:22ff7fca8d3f6607114dc22d
          member_id:2022,
          member_name:"George",  
          address:String,
          sex:String
        }


         }]
```

How can I do this in mongoose.

Comment: Hi , you want to do this in one shot ?

Comment: It would be better ... If it is possible in one shot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the aggregation pipeline like this

db.collection.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$country",count:{$sum:"$member_count"},"members":{$push:"$member
"}}}])

Thanks,
Rohit